# Кавычки в JS кнопки отправки сообщения

Tags: javascript

1. У меня есть форма заявки на сайте с кнопкой:

```js
<a onclick = "ym (XXXXX," desireGoal "," TEST "); return true;" class = "button button_long last">Отправить данные</a>
```

2. Для начала я создаю цель в Я.Метрике и получаю идентификатор для сайта.
3. Установил данный идентификатор в ссылку (код выше), которая является кнопкой отправки сообщения с формы.
4. Рабочий вариант кода для отслеживания целей, выглядит следующим образом (для вставки в кнопку отправки сообщения):

```js
onclick = "ym (XXXXX, 'desireGoal', 'TEST'); return true;"
```

Проблема вот в чем:

А) С двойными кавычками получаю в итоге ошибку синтаксиса, после нажатия кнопки: Uncaught SyntaxError...

Б) Почему бы не прописать с одинарными кавычками - как есть? Из-за того, что у меня форма заявки сложная, и визуально кнопка для нажатия в конце появляется после проверки, вариант с одинарными кавычками ломает всю форму заявки.

Примеру, часть кода:

```js
if (! err_fields) {$ (". box.last .button_controller"). append ('Отправить данные'). find ("a.last"). css ("курсор", "указатель"). click (function ( ) {send_data_brif ();}); } paneHeight (); }
```

Попрошу подсказать, как могу не нарушая работу формы заявки, сохранить одинарные кавычки, тем самым отслеживать цели в Я.Метрике. Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит `вариант с одинарными кавычками ломает всю форму заявки`? У вас что-то не работает или как это проявляется?

Comment: Вот, что происходит. 1) Если код вставляю таким образом:  if(!err_fields){
  $(".box.last .button_controller").append('<a onclick="ym(XXXXXX, "reachGoal", "TEST"); return true;" class="button button_long last">Отправить данные</a>').find("a.last").css("cursor","pointer").click(function(){
   send_data_brif();
  });
 }
 paneHeight();
} - тогда форма заявки работает, но цель в YM не отслеживается (в браузере в отладке показывает ошибку).

Comment: Как только исправляю на такой вариант. 2)  if(!err_fields){
  $(".box.last .button_controller").append('<a onclick="ym(XXXXXXXX, 'reachGoal', 'TEST'); return true;" class="button button_long last">Отправить данные</a>').find("a.last").css("cursor","pointer").click(function(){
   send_data_brif();
  });
 }
 paneHeight();
} - прекращает работать сама форма.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно создать строку, в которой используются внутри друг друга двойные и одинарные кавычки. В таком случае у вас есть два выбора:

1. Экранировать кавычки внутри строки (те, которые совпадают с самыми внешними):

```js
.append('<a onclick="ym(XXXXXX, \'reachGoal\', \'TEST\'); return true;" class="button button_long last">Отправить данные</a>')
```

2. В качестве самых внешних кавычек использовать обратные (backticks, `` ` ``):

```js
.append(`<a onclick="ym(XXXXXX, 'reachGoal', 'TEST'); return true;" class="button button_long last">Отправить данные</a>`)
```

Comment: Спасибо, за варианты! Сделал, вроде ошибка пропала, первый вариант прошел в YM.